# Using jQuery to populate a DropDownList with items and their optgroups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am still learning jQuery/json and am struggling to figure out how to include optgroups when building my DropDownList via jQuery using json data.

Here is an example of the json data:

```
0:
  Disabled: false
  Group:
    Disabled: false
    Name: "Property Overview"
  Selected: false
  Text: "Number of Floors"
  Value: "277"
```

Currently, I am able to populate the DropDownList with the Text and Value. That is fairly straight forward. Here is my code for that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PropertyList").on('change', function () {

            $("#Options_Question").empty();
            var id = $("#PropertyList").val();
            var url = '@Url.Action("GetPropertyTypeSpecificQuestions", "Report", new { id = "replaceToken" })';
            url = url.replace("replaceToken", id);

            $.getJSON(url, null, function (data) {
                $("#Options_Question").addQuestions(data);
            });
        });

        $.fn.addQuestions = function (data) {
            return this.each(function () {
                var list = this;
                $.each(data, function (index, questionData) {
                    var option = new Option(questionData.Text, questionData.Value);
                    list.add(option);
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

How can I edit my jQuery to include the values from Group.Name and group the questions into their respective optgroups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working using information found in various places around stackoverflow. Here is the working jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PropertyList").on('change', function () {

            $("#Options_Question").empty();
            var id = $("#PropertyList").val();
            var url = '@Url.Action("GetPropertyTypeSpecificQuestions", "Report", new { id = "replaceToken" })';
            url = url.replace("replaceToken", id);

            $.getJSON(url, null, function (data) {
                $("#Options_Question").addQuestions(data);
            });
        });

        $.fn.addQuestions = function (data) {
            var prevGroup, prevGroupName;

            $.each(data, function () {
                if (this.Group.Name == null) {
                    $("<option />").val(this.Value).text(this.Text).appendTo("#Options_Question");
                }
                else if (prevGroupName != this.Group.Name) {
                    prevGroup = $('<optgroup />').prop('label', this.Group.Name).appendTo('#Options_Question');
                }
                $("<option />").val(this.Value).text(this.Text).appendTo(prevGroup);
                prevGroupName = this.Group.Name;
            });  
        }
    });
```